# CIDetector.RectDetector bounds to view bounds coordinates

Tags: ios, xamarin, avcapturesession

So,

I am trying to display a rectanlge around a detected document (A4)
I am using an AVCaptureSession for the feed along with the AVCaptureStillImageOutput Output.

```
NSError Error = null;
        Session = new AVCaptureSession();
        AVCaptureDevice Device = AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
        AVCaptureDeviceInput DeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(Device, out Error);
        Session.AddInput(DeviceInput);
        AVCaptureStillImageOutput CaptureOutput = new AVCaptureStillImageOutput();
        CaptureOutput.OutputSettings = new NSDictionary(AVVideo.CodecKey, AVVideo.CodecJPEG) ;

        Session.AddOutput(CaptureOutput);
```

I have a timer that takes the output and passes that to my handler

```
 NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:02"), delegate
            {

                CaptureImageWithMetadata(CaptureOutput,CaptureOutput.Connections[0]);
            });
```

I also have an AVCapturePreviewLayer with its bound being full screen (iPad Mini Portrait)

```
 PreviewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(Session);
        PreviewLayer.Frame = this.View.Frame;
        PreviewLayer.VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill;
        this.View.Layer.AddSublayer(PreviewLayer);
        PreviewLayer.ZPosition = (PreviewLayer.ZPosition - 1);
```

Below is the handler

```
private async void CaptureImageWithMetadata(AVCaptureStillImageOutput output, AVCaptureConnection connection)
    {
        var sampleBuffer = await output.CaptureStillImageTaskAsync(connection);
        var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.JpegStillToNSData(sampleBuffer);

        var image = CIImage.FromData(imageData);
        var metadata = image.Properties.Dictionary.MutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary;

        CIContext CT = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
        CIDetectorOptions OP = new CIDetectorOptions();
        OP.Accuracy = FaceDetectorAccuracy.High;
        OP.AspectRatio = 1.41f;
        CIDetector CI = CIDetector.CreateRectangleDetector(CT, OP);
        CIFeature[] HH = CI.FeaturesInImage(image,CIImageOrientation.BottomRight);

        CGAffineTransform Transfer = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1, -1);
        Transfer = CGAffineTransform.Translate(Transfer, 0, -this.View.Bounds.Size.Height);

        if (HH.Length > 0)
        {
            CGRect RECT = CGAffineTransform.CGRectApplyAffineTransform(HH[0].Bounds, Transfer);


            Console.WriteLine("start");
            Console.WriteLine("IMAGE : "+HH[0].Bounds.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("SCREEN :"+RECT.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("end");

            BB.Frame = RECT;
            BB.Hidden = false;


        }



    }
```

Despite however after following a guid that suggested I need to convert the coordinates - my highlighter (green) is not surround the document, and i cant figure out why.

I am using `CIImageOrientation.BottomRight` just as test but no matter what i put here.. always the same result. See Images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?